# Qt Application not started if codesign with Entitlements file

Tags: macos, qt, qt5, codesign, entitlements

Have qt project for macOS. Try codesign with entitlements file.
(Qt 5.14.2, macOs 10.15.4, Xcode 11.4)

**First build option**: sh script with qmake, make, macdeployqt, codesign...
(library libqcocoa.dylib is in the result bundle: myapp.app/Contents/PlugIns/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib)

When applying Codesign without entitlements-file, the program starts normally.

```
/usr/bin/codesign -s "Apple Development: ..." ./myapp.app
```

If Entitlements are added, the program does not start.

```
/usr/bin/codesign -s "Apple Development: ..." ./myapp.app --entitlements ../Mac/myapp.entitlements
```

If run it from the console

```
zsh: killed
```

**Second build option**
Use qmake to get xcode project

```
.../Qt5.14.2/5.14.2/clang_64/bin/qmake ../myapp/myapp.pro -r -spec macx-xcode "CONFIG+=release"
```

build project and run it in Xcode (with Entitlements):

```
[qt.qpa.plugin] Could not find the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in ""
```

build project and run it in Xcode (without Entitlements): program starts normally

Entitlements file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension</key>
    <array>
        <string>app-proxy-provider</string>
        <string>content-filter-provider</string>
        <string>dns-proxy</string>
        <string>packet-tunnel-provider</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.networking.vpn.api</key>
    <array>
        <string>allow-vpn</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.server</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```